# just general advice on IDE and tools

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

we're being pushed to phonegap for a project that needs done asap.  I'm just wondering what those out there see as the best interface for phonegap.  This app is going to be built for Android but should render on both devices.  I can use a Mac or PC, environment makes no different, unfortunately version control is only present on the PC.  I personally was thinking Dreamweaver.. but then I start hearing Notepad, Chrome, and the standard Eclipse environment.  Anyone wanna give me some general direction, decent links whatever.  btw.. this is enterprise so the backend will probably be more pertinent than the UI.

oh I'm experienced in both OS's, but only slightly at HTML5.  I very much prefer doing things natively vs. say.. PhoneGap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer you using MAC OS because both Android and iOS development can be done on it.
You will have to setup the environment for phonegap for both the mobile OS.
For Iphone you will need Xcode, developer license & phonegap(iOS version). For Android you will need Eclipse,Android SDK & phonegap(Android Version).

For iOS Setup guide can be found here [iOS Guide](http://phonegap.com/start#ios-x4)

For Android Setup guide can be found here [Android Guide](http://phonegap.com/start#android)

Native coding is always better then others but phonegap will provide you standardization.Just write the code once and it can be used in many OS apart from android & iOS.

And you have knowledge of both OS.So it will be easy for you.You just need to learn little bit of HTML5 & JavaScript.

Comment: I have seen and addon that links to Dreamweaver, I also recently just saw an addon to Chrome called AppMobi specifically for PhoneGap.  I've used appMobi before only for HTML5 development.  Any opinion on either of these two?